# Storing data and using it on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, query-string

My WP7 application consists of:
***login page***: in which I insert a user name and password and clicking a button send XML request and i get an XML file from which I take a user_id that I have to store it somewhere  can use it.
***Friends page***: send a request containing user_id and i get list of friends in an xml file that I have to parse to display the list but I have to store friend_id too because once the user selects a friend in the list it will navigate to another page displaying the information in this friend and that using a url containing friend_id.
The problem is , in login page i used the querystring method to re-use user_id and it worked, but int friends page it didn't work, and i didn't find a simple way to store my friends info and re-use them again especially because of the xml parsing below:

```
  void friends_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(e.Result));
            var items = from item in doc.Element("information").Elements("item")
                        select new User
                        {
                            id = item.Element("id").Value,
                            nom = item.Element("nom").Value,
                            photo = item.Element("photo").Value
                        };
            listBoxFriends.ItemsSource = items;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Video/gg241265) for saving app related information.

For more of an [overview see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to save the ids. You can use the IsolatedStorage which persists for the application

```
IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
List<int> friendidList = new List<int>();
userSettings.Add("friend_ids", friendidList);
userSettings.Save();
```

to get the values back

```
object friendids;
userSettings.TryGetValue("friend_ids", out friendids);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use PhoneApplictaionStates/ Isolated Storage for storing the data. 
for eg :-
you can save the username to state like this
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State[key] = userName.Text; // here key is the identifier 
for retrieving the username
string userName = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State[key];
```

Comment: Could you please explain more this method ;)

Comment: http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-8-what.html